Docker Compose Container Crashing in GitLab Runner - No write access
I'm using a Docker runner in my GitLab setup to build a Docker image for my application tests. The image is a Keycloak container with some preconfigured settings.
I've created a build.sh script that uses Docker Compose. I mount the Keycloak data directory with - ./data:/opt/keycloak/data/. However, the container crashes with errors when I start it.
Pipeline steps
build-keycloak-test-image:
  stage: build-keycloak-test-image
  before_script:
    - echo $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD | docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER --password-stdin $CI_REGISTRY
    - apk add --no-cache curl
    - chmod +x ./keycloak/test/build.sh
  script:
    - cd ./keycloak/test/
    - sh ./build.sh
    - docker push $KEYCLOAK_TEST_IMAGE
  only:
    - tags

Build Script
#!/bin/bash
KEYCLOAK_URL="${KEYCLOAK_TEST_GEN_URL:-http://localhost:8889}"
# Endpoint to be checked
HEALTH_ENDPOINT="/health"

rm -fr ./data/*
mkdir ./data
chmod -R 777 ./data/
docker compose up -d
# ...

Logs
Here are some logs after starting the container:
2024-09-13 15:07:03,053 INFO  [org.keycloak.common.Profile] (main) Preview features enabled: token-exchange
2024-09-13 15:07:12,589 INFO  [io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor] (main) Quarkus augmentation completed in 10289ms
2024-09-13 15:07:13,837 INFO  [org.keycloak.common.Profile] (main) Preview features enabled: token-exchange
2024-09-13 15:07:14,520 INFO  [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.hostname.DefaultHostnameProvider] (main) Hostname settings: Base URL: <unset>, Hostname: <request>, Strict HTTPS: false, Path: <request>, Strict BackChannel: false, Admin URL: <unset>, Admin: <request>, Port: -1, Proxied: false
2024-09-13 15:07:17,244 WARN  [io.quarkus.agroal.runtime.DataSources] (main) Datasource <default> enables XA but transaction recovery is not enabled. Please enable transaction recovery by setting quarkus.transaction-manager.enable-recovery=true, otherwise data may be lost if the application is terminated abruptly
2024-09-13 15:07:17,928 WARN  [org.infinispan.PERSISTENCE] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000554: jboss-marshalling is deprecated and planned for removal
2024-09-13 15:07:17,966 WARN  [org.infinispan.CONFIG] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000569: Unable to persist Infinispan internal caches as no global state enabled
2024-09-13 15:07:18,052 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.infinispan.jboss.marshalling.core.JBossUserMarshaller'
org.h2.message.DbException: Log file error: "/opt/keycloak/data/h2/keycloakdb.trace.db", cause: "org.h2.message.DbException: Error while creating file ""/opt/keycloak/data/h2"" [90062-224]" [90034-224]
org.h2.message.DbException: Log file error: "/opt/keycloak/data/h2/keycloakdb.trace.db", cause: "org.h2.message.DbException: Error while creating file ""/opt/keycloak/data/h2"" [90062-224]" [90034-224]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:212)
    at org.h2.message.TraceSystem.logWritingError(TraceSystem.java:327)
    at org.h2.message.TraceSystem.openWriter(TraceSystem.java:348)
    at org.h2.message.TraceSystem.writeFile(TraceSystem.java:296)
    at org.h2.message.TraceSystem.write(TraceSystem.java:280)
    at org.h2.message.Trace.error(Trace.java:187)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:397)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:92)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:222)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:201)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:343)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:125)
    at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource.getXAConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:322)
    at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:232)
    at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:536)
    at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:517)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at io.agroal.pool.util.PriorityScheduledExecutor.beforeExecute(PriorityScheduledExecutor.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: Log file error: "/opt/keycloak/data/h2/keycloakdb.trace.db", cause: "org.h2.message.DbException: Error while creating file ""/opt/keycloak/data/h2"" [90062-224]" [90034-224]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:566)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:489)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.h2.message.DbException: Error while creating file "/opt/keycloak/data/h2" [90062-224]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:212)
    at org.h2.store.fs.disk.FilePathDisk.createDirectory(FilePathDisk.java:391)
    at org.h2.store.fs.FileUtils.createDirectory(FileUtils.java:85)
    at org.h2.store.fs.FileUtils.createDirectories(FileUtils.java:382)
    at org.h2.message.TraceSystem.openWriter(TraceSystem.java:338)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: Error while creating file "/opt/keycloak/data/h2" [90062-224]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:566)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:489)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /opt/keycloak/data/h2
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:397)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:700)
    at org.h2.store.fs.disk.FilePathDisk.createDirectory(FilePathDisk.java:382)
    ... 21 more
2024-09-13 15:07:20,174 WARN  [io.agroal.pool] (agroal-11) Datasource '<default>': Error while creating file "/opt/keycloak/data/h2" [90062-224]
2024-09-13 15:07:20,177 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator] (JPA Startup Thread) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(java.sql.SQLException, String)" because the return value of "org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaIsolationDelegate.sqlExceptionHelper()" is null
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaIsolationDelegate.doTheWork(JtaIsolationDelegate.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaIsolationDelegate.lambda$delegateWork$1(JtaIsolationDelegate.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaIsolationDelegate.doInSuspendedTransaction(JtaIsolationDelegate.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JtaIsolationDelegate.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:239)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.<init>(SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.java:273)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.recording.PrevalidatedQuarkusMetadata.buildSessionFactoryOptionsBuilder(PrevalidatedQuarkusMetadata.java:70)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.boot.FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.build(FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.java:81)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.FastBootHibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(FastBootHibernatePersistenceProvider.java:74)
    at jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:80)
    at jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig$LazyPersistenceUnit.get(JPAConfig.java:156)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig$1.run(JPAConfig.java:64)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

2024-09-13 15:07:21,152 INFO  [org.keycloak.connections.infinispan.DefaultInfinispanConnectionProviderFactory] (main) Node name: node_491456, Site name: null
org.h2.message.DbException: Log file error: "/opt/keycloak/data/h2/keycloakdb.trace.db", cause: "org.h2.message.DbException: Error while creating file ""/opt/keycloak/data/h2"" [90062-224]" [90034-224]
org.h2.message.DbException: Log file error: "/opt/keycloak/data/h2/keycloakdb.trace.db", cause: "org.h2.message.DbException: Error while creating file ""/opt/keycloak/data/h2"" [90062-224]" [90034-224]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:212)
    at org.h2.message.TraceSystem.logWritingError(TraceSystem.java:327)
    at org.h2.message.TraceSystem.openWriter(TraceSystem.java:348)
    at org.h2.message.TraceSystem.writeFile(TraceSystem.java:296)
    at org.h2.message.TraceSystem.write(TraceSystem.java:280)
    at org.h2.message.Trace.error(Trace.java:187)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:397)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:92)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:222)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:201)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:343)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:125)
    at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource.getXAConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:322)
    at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:232)
    at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:536)
    at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:517)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at io.agroal.pool.util.PriorityScheduledExecutor.beforeExecute(PriorityScheduledExecutor.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: Log file error: "/opt/keycloak/data/h2/keycloakdb.trace.db", cause: "org.h2.message.DbException: Error while creating file ""/opt/keycloak/data/h2"" [90062-224]" [90034-224]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:566)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:489)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.h2.message.DbException: Error while creating file "/opt/keycloak/data/h2" [90062-224]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:212)
    at org.h2.store.fs.disk.FilePathDisk.createDirectory(FilePathDisk.java:391)
    at org.h2.store.fs.FileUtils.createDirectory(FileUtils.java:85)
    at org.h2.store.fs.FileUtils.createDirectories(FileUtils.java:382)
    at org.h2.message.TraceSystem.openWriter(TraceSystem.java:338)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: Error while creating file "/opt/keycloak/data/h2" [90062-224]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:566)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:489)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /opt/keycloak/data/h2
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:397)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:700)
    at org.h2.store.fs.disk.FilePathDisk.createDirectory(FilePathDisk.java:382)
    ... 21 more
2024-09-13 15:07:23,831 WARN  [io.agroal.pool] (agroal-11) Datasource '<default>': Error while creating file "/opt/keycloak/data/h2" [90062-224]
2024-09-13 15:07:23,908 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to start server in (development) mode
2024-09-13 15:07:23,909 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to obtain JDBC connection
2024-09-13 15:07:23,910 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Error while creating file "/opt/keycloak/data/h2" [90062-224]
2024-09-13 15:07:23,910 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: /opt/keycloak/data/h2
2024-09-13 15:07:23,912 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) For more details run the same command passing the '--verbose' option. Also you can use '--help' to see the details about the usage of the particular command.

Docker Compose file
services:
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.6
    ports:
      - "8889:8080"
    command:
      - start-dev
    volumes:
      - ./data:/opt/keycloak/data/
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: "admin"
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: "mypass"
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: true
      KC_METRICS_ENABLED: true
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: false
      KC_HTTP_ENABLED: false
      KC_FEATURES: "token-exchange"
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: true
    networks:
      - gitlab
      - default
networks:
  gitlab:
    name: gitlab-network


Observations
My script should create the data directory and set permissions to 777, so any process should write to it. I checked inside the container:
# ls /builds/dev/project/keycloak/test/ -lah
total 24K
drwxrwxrwx    3 root     root        4.0K Sep 13 15:06 .
drwxrwxrwx    7 root     root        4.0K Sep  4 12:56 ..
...
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root        4.0K Sep 13 15:06 data

Everything works fine on my local machine, but the container fails in the GitLab environment.
Question
Does anyone know why the Docker container crashes with these errors? Any help would be appreciated!

The reason of this error is that within running container current user is keyckloak:

uid=1000(keycloak) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)

but directory /opt/keycloak/data/ is being created with root restrictions and without write-permissions for the group:

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Oct 31 19:21 /opt/keycloak/data/

One of workarounds here could be to make the current user as root within container, adding the user: root directive to the docker compose file:
services:
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.6
    user: root
...

The second option is to create transitive service within the docker compose that would prelimitary set the appropriate owner for the mounted volume like described here:
Or, eventually, to build a custom image extending the keycloak and perform all this permission manipulations at the image build stage.
This permission checking that you do (ls /builds/dev/project/keycloak/test/ -lah) is aparently not inside the container but within the scope of GitLab's job (where you launched the build.sh providing full permissions to the ./data/ directory).
To check the actual directory permissions inside container you can tempopary replace the "command" directive within the docker-compose file to following one:

entrypoint: ["ls", "-lhd", "/opt/keycloak/data/"]

